# trouble using make and #include

Tags: c, include, makefile

I have a project that has three files. The main file is called login.c.
I want to #include my other two files using make, but I'm having trouble doing so.
Thanks in advance for any advice!!

here is my makefile:

```
objects = login.o cipher.o linked.o
coptions = -Wall -g -ggdb

loginTest: ${objects}
    gcc ${coptions} -o loginTest ${objects}
login.o: login.c cipher.h linked.h
    gcc -c ${coptions} login.c 
cipher.o: cipher.c cipher.h
    gcc -c ${coptions} cipher.c
linked.o: linked.c linked.h
    gcc -c ${coptions} linked.c
```

the error I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `cipher.h', needed by `login.o'.  Stop.
```

the files in my current working directory:

```
cipher.c
linked.c
linked.o
login.c
makefile
```

Comment: Is your cipher.h in the same directory with login.c?

Comment: yes, they are all in the same directory

Comment: Check the file names again. And remember, in a UNIX-like environment (like Linux, OSX, and depending on settings Cygwin) file names are _case sensitive_.

Comment: Can you give us a list of files in that directory?

Comment: @louxiu I've just added them

Comment: @agarrow So the *.h file is not in current directory. So you need to change cipher.h to path/cipher.h.

Comment: @louxiu the .h file doesn't yet exist, this makefile needs to create it

Comment: @agarrow No... makefile can't create *.h file for u. You need to create it by yourself.

Comment: @louxiu ah you're right, thanks for straightening me out. Still getting the hang of this stuff :) sorry for wasting anyones time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make can not automatically  create *.h.

You need to create it and #include that *.h file by yourself.